# Lambda to S3 image upload shows a black background with white square

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to upload an image file from a form-data multivalue request to S3. There are now no errors in the console but what is saved to S3 is a black background with a white sqaure which im sure is down to a corrupt file or something.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using aws-lambda-multipart-parser to parse the form data.

In my console the form actual image is getting logged like this.

[image]

My upload file function looks like this

```
const uploadFile = async(image: any) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: image.filename,
        Body: image.content,
        ContentType: image.contentType,
    }
    return await S3.putObject(params).promise()
}
```

When I log the image.content I get a log of the buffer, which seems to be the format i should be uploading the image to.

My CDK stack initialises the S3 contsruct like so.

```
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "WidgetStore");

bucket.grantWrite(handler);
bucket.grantPublicAccess();
table.grantStreamRead(handler);
handler.addToRolePolicy(lambdaPolicy);



const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "widgets-api", {
  restApiName: "Widget Service",
  description: "This service serves widgets.",
  binaryMediaTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
  
});
```

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd rephrase this a little bit... while you use the CDK to create the resources in AWS this doesn't seem to be related to the CDK directly. There is an issue happening between the API Gateway and the Lambda function with the parsing of the body. I can't say for sure what, but I worry having "CDK" in the title and lead may turn away AWS Serverless developers that can lend a hand.

Comment: OK good idea. i didnt know whether it maybe something in the resource creation that i was maybe missing? But defo see what you mean.